# Exponential of a uniform integrable martingale is a submartingale

Tags: stochastic-processes, martingales, uniform-integrability

For reference I want to prove this Lemma:

Let $M$ be a uniformly integrable martingale with the additional
property that $\mathbb{E}[ \exp(M_\infty)] < 1$. Then $\exp(M)$ is a uniformly integrable submartingale.

My attempt of a proof:

As $M$ is a martingale we have that $\mathbb{E} \left[ M_t \mid \mathcal{F}_s \right] = M_s$ for all $t \geq s$. Now by Jensen's conditional inequality as the function $\exp(x)$ is convex we have:
$$ \exp(M_s) = \exp\left(\mathbb{E} \left[ M_t \mid \mathcal{F}_s \right]\right) \leq \mathbb{E} \left[ \exp(M_t) \mid \mathcal{F}_s \right].$$
Therefore $\exp(M)$ satisfies the submartingale property and as the exponential is a measurable function we have that $\exp(M)$ is also adapted to the filtration of the martingale $M$. Hence $M$ is a submartingale.

But now how can I prove that $\exp(M)$ is uniform integrable? I don't really know how to apply that $\mathbb{E}[ \exp(M_\infty)] < 1$. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you know Doob's inequality?

Comment: $P \left(\sup_{0\leq t \leq \infty} \exp(M_t) > \epsilon \right) \leq \frac{\mathbb{E} [\exp(M_\infty)]}{\epsilon}$? I'm not sure how that would help me with uniform integrability.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To show U.I.,

\begin{align}
&\mathbb{E}[\exp(M_s);\exp(M_s)\geq K] &&  
 \\
&\leq \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[\exp(M_\infty)|\mathcal{F}_s]; \exp(M_s)\geq K] &&  \text{(submartingale property})\\
& \leq\mathbb{E}[\exp(M_\infty); \exp(M_s)\geq K]
\end{align}

Hence you need only to show that $\sup_{0\leq s\leq \infty}\mathbb{P}[\exp(M_s)\geq K]\to 0$ as $K\to \infty$, which you can do using Doob's inequality.

---

And just to explain the notation: $$\mathbb{E}[X;A]:=\int_A X(\omega)\mathrm{d}\mathbb{P}(\omega)$$

Comment: To use Doob's inequality doesn't the supremum need to be inside the probability measure?

Comment: @Rodel $\sup_{0\leq s\leq \infty}\mathbb{P}[\exp(M_s)\geq K]\leq \mathbb{P}[\sup_{0\leq s\leq \infty}\exp(M_s)\geq K]$

Comment: Am I mistaken or is it then sufficient to have $\mathbb{E} \exp(M_\infty) < \infty$?

Comment: Yes that is sufficient.